# get the path of the project in C#

Tags: c#

how do I get the path of the project?
i want to assign a string with the path of the folder of the project.
lets say, the folder of my project (in C#) is E:\projects\something
(in folder something, I have the .sln file and all the source codes and also a folder pictures, and in some function I want to assign a string to the path of the project's folder for after it use fhe files in pictures... what I need is a function retorning the path of the project.
string s=project_path;

Comment: Not enough info. Where do you want to get it? Inside your application? Inside a VS addin? Manually? ...?

Comment: @jerry: Update your question with the requested details and flag it for moderator attention, so it can be reopened. Your recent update is not enough. Note: The project is the stuff you compile, i.e. *.cs files. The running program is the assembly. Please clarify.

Comment: @jerry: see my last comment. Your update doesn't make it any clearer.

Comment: @jerry: Where do you want this code to run? Because as soon as your program is compiled, you could even delete that folder... What do you **really** want to achieve?

Comment: There is no reason why the compiled program should know where the sourcecode is.

Comment: @CodeInChaos: That's what I am saying...

Comment: hi what all I want is just to get my project file and save it in string variable .

Comment: I am sorry "to get my project file path ... "

Answer (score 2):

```
private void button1_Click(object sender, System.EventArgs e)
{
   string path;
   path = System.IO.Path.GetDirectoryName( 
      System.Reflection.Assembly.GetExecutingAssembly().GetName().CodeBase );
   MessageBox.Show( path );
}
```